# What is actually itemLimit in FineUploader?

Tags: amazon-s3, fine-uploader

I am successfully using FineUploader with Amazon S3 but when the item limit is set, let's say to "3", I am not able to upload more than 3 files unless I refresh the page. So, what do you mean by "session" when saying in the documentation:

"Maximum number of items that can be potentially uploaded in this session. Will reject all items that are added or retried after this limit is reached."

I thought that "session" is one upload round - take 3 files and upload them, then take 3 more or less than 3 and upload them and so on.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of [itemLimit](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options.html#validation.itemLimit), the "session" is simply the current instance of Fine Uploader. To start a new "session", you would construct a new instance of that Fine Uploader object, either by a page refresh or programmatically.