# Upload a single file with FineUploader in basic mode, error after second upload

Tags: fine-uploader

I am working on allowing only a single file to be uploaded via FineUploader in basic (Non-UI mode). I have set the 'itemLimit: 1' inside the validation options. This works fine and I see the error message: "Too many items (3) would be uploaded. Item limit is 1." if I select 3 files instead 1 file.

Now, when I select 1 file, and upload it, I click the upload button again and try to select 3 files again, but this time it says "Too many items (4) would be uploaded. Item limit is 1." even though I have selected only 3 files. So, now if I select only 1 file, it gives me an error saying: "Too many items (2) would be uploaded. Item limit is 1." even though only 1 file was selected. Is this a bug?

I guess what I am really asking, is, how do I make FineUploader accept only 1 file for upload at any given time when FineUploader instance has been constructed in basic (non-UI) mode?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain that I already answered this concept in a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33868222/what-is-actually-itemlimit-in-fineuploader):

> In the case of [itemLimit](http://docs.fineuploader.com/api/options.html#validation.itemLimit), the "session" is simply the current
>   instance of Fine Uploader. To start a new "session", you would
>   construct a new instance of that Fine Uploader object, either by a
>   page refresh or programmatically.

Comment: Hi, Dan thanks for your suggestion. But it seems illogical to me to construct a new instance of FineUploader after an upload, and neither should the user refresh the page. What should happen, at least in my mind, is that the file that has already been uploaded should not be counted towards a new selection of files. Please re-read the original question, you will see that this is what's happening.

Comment: Since there is no obvious reason why you would want to limit the number of files the user can select at one time, this feature counts the total number of files per session.

Comment: I wanted to use this for uploading a profile picture. So the user shouldn't be able to select more than 1 image file. That is the requirement.

Comment: Take a look at the `multiple` boolean option as a possibility.

Comment: Bingo! that's it:) I was looking at this yesterday but I was on the ui options documentation page, and got left with a feeling that it was only available in that mode...now that I think about it, it wasn't smart to think that, and I should have search for core options. Thank you Ray!